# VBA Error: Out of stack space

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a very simple macro in an Excel sheet, to allows users to recalculate.

**I have no other macros/code in the workbook, and only this work book open**

```
Sub Calculate()
    Calculate
End Sub
```

This is activated by a button.

However, when pressed I get two error boxes, see image.

What does `Out of stack space mean` ? 
And how do I resolve this issue ?
[image]

I have looked on this website:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/out-of-stack-space-error-28

It says I may have too many funtions ??
This macro used to work fine, and it is hardly doing a lot so cannot understand the issue.

I am able to calculate the sheet using the option under the formulas tab.

Comment: You have written a re-entrant function which calls itself unconditionally without restraining conditions, so it will fill the stack with the repeated calls. What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: @AFH all the macro should do is calculate the sheet, a user enters a new date, and then hits the refresh button to re-calculate. the user may not be excel savvy, so I used the macro/button as you can't miss it then.

Comment: Without seeing the underlying code it would be hard to provide a definitive answer as to the direct cause as there can be a few reasons - recursive function, variables consuming too much memory. As per your link, the stack is an area of working memory allocated and when you execute your macro the variables and calls it makes are 'pushed' onto the stack. When a function or variable is no longer required it is removed from the stack, freeing memory. The  error suggests that your macro may be exceeding the allocated memory for the stack.

Comment: @Enigman the only code used in the document is shown in the question, I have no other macros, this is why I am so baffled by this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you have define is recursive, calling itself unconditionally until the stack is filled with all the calls.

You should change the name of your subroutine, eg:-

```
Sub Calc()
    Calculate
End Sub
```

If you link `Calc()` to the button, you avoid any recursion.

Comment: this has solved the issue thanks !, still a bit baffled by it though, as the problem only started today and worked fine for the last few weeks.

Comment: I can't explain how it worked before, unless another revision handled the calls  differently.

Comment: I've worked with compilers [mono] that would separate two visually identical commands in a scope to be separate entities to the compiled script, even though they share a name in plaintext. idk VBA, but it may have done something similar... but no longer does. It could actually be a bug if it's meant to be 'smart' in those circumstances.

Comment: @Tetsujin - I had assumed it must be something like that. Maybe it's to do with when the function becomes defined. If it's unknown as a function name until its definition is complete, then during the definition the `Calculate` call must link to the system function. The method of linking may have changed, but this is only speculation.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling Calculate inside of Calculate. Every call to Calculate causes another call to Calculate, which will then call Calculate... Then eventually you get that error when the stack fills up.

Comment: so the calculate function in the code, cause my macro to re-calculate also ? I use this exact same macro in other workbooks without any problem

Comment: @PeterH You might have been lucky up to now that it hadn't manifested earlier. Perhaps there was more space on the stack on other occasions - more apps might have been running on the workstation this time or it had been a longer time between reboots of the workstation. It's why we have to be careful when using names for modules and functions as using a reserved word or inbuilt function name can bite us later on as was the case in this situation.

Comment: Well thanks for your help anyway, I didn't realize the name of a function really mattered to be honest